# Misconception regarding onLocationChange

Tags: android, locationlistener

Let me give you a brief background.

I need to check the users location *either after some time or after some distance*. So I am using LocationListner class to track the location. To test it on Emulator, I have created on .gpx file to set the direction. and I am getting the location on emulator currently on button click. But **how will I be able to get the updated location based on distance or time.** 
As stated by develper.adnroid

```
You can control the frequency at which your listener receives updates with the second 
and third parameter—the second is the minimum time interval between notifications and
the third is the minimum change in distance between notifications—setting both to
zero requests location notifications as frequently as possible.
```

But I am not getting the expected result. Do any body know What's wrong I am doing.??

**Code Snippets**

On button click this piece of code execute

```
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            MyLocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener(this, locManager);
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
            if (isGPSEnabled) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Called isGPSEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000, 0, locListener);
                }
```

**FYI: toast inside if is called.**

And this is my onLoactionChange. Adding this method only as rest methods are empty.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
           if(location != null)
        {
            locManager.removeUpdates(this);

            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());       
            List<Address>  addresses; 
            try
            {  
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);  
                if (addresses.size() > 0)
                {
                    String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "\n";
                    cityName = cityName + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                    TextView tvInfo = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.tv_info);
                    tvInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tvInfo.setText("Curent address is" + cityName + "Latitude :" + addresses.get(0).getLatitude() + "Longitude :" +addresses.get(0).getLongitude());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {           
                //Toast
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } 
        }
    }
```

Manifest have permissions as

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Result:**
Once button is clicked it gives the current location. but remains that only all the time.

**Expected result**: Either after some time or some distance moved current location should update.

Can any bode help me in achieving this. or point out where am I doing wrong.??

Comment: are testing it inside the room if you are doing please come outside test i.because sometimes gps receiver doesn't getting fixes inside a room.

Comment: I am doing on emulator using Fake location. So there won't be any problem as inside and outside :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I need to remove `locManager.removeUpdates(this);`

Removing this line enabled my application to receive update on emulator.