# Do onLocationChange get called by itself

Tags: android, locationlistener

I have one simple question. As Android Developer [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates) states:

> You can control the frequency at which your listener receives updates
>   with the
>       second and third parameter—the second is the minimum time interval between
>       notifications and the third is the minimum change in distance between 
>       notifications—setting both to zero requests location notifications as 
>       frequently as possible.

But I have never seen `onLocationChange` called by itself. Does `onLocationChange` is ever called by itself. Either on time basis or distance basis. If yes how it can be replicated.

I have added this line in my code `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 200000, 100, locListener);`

but `location` never changes by itself. Do I need to add some other things too.

Comment: Try this:  locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 200000, 100, this); Have you used the method onLocationChanged?

Comment: What does "by itself" mean? Nothing can be called by itself. Android calls onLocationChanged() on your listener when a GPS receiver device receives an update. By providing frequency values you control how often should this devices look up for the updates.

Comment: @ling.s My listner is different class so I have to pass instance of my listner so I don't think so I need to pass this. Anyways thanks for comments

Comment: @Egor What I understood from andriod.developer quote is, onLocationChange() will be called after each 2 min if we pass 120000 as paramter in `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000, 100, locListener);` So I was expecting my onLocationChange will again be called even if location is not changed. Tell if I m wrong.

Comment: @random4Infinity, No, it won't ever be called if the location hasn't changed, nevermind the frequency parameters you supply.

Comment: @Egor So why do we have the parameter if its not used. And One more thing how can we simulate the distance moved in emulator if that can make it show a demo. Can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876575/misconception-regarding-onlocationchange?noredirect=1. As this will solve my problem tooo

Comment: @random4Infinity, If you set minimum frequency to 2 minutes and, the onLocationChanged() won't get called more often than 2 minutes, even if the updates are available every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that event.

```
`LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 locListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
               try {

                   lat = location.getLatitude ();
                   lon = location.getLongitude ();


                   mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(lat, lon));
                   //or something


                 }
                 catch (NullPointerException e){
                   lat = -1.0;
                   lon = -1.0;
                 }
        }`
```

And to add it in some event (onCreate, onClick ect..)

Comment: I have done exactly like this. but onLocationChange() is never called again and also I have added this `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000, 100, locListener);`